# Regular expression parsing a binary file?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, parsing, binary

I have a file which mixes binary data and text data. I want to parse it through a regular expression, but I get this error:

```
TypeError: can't use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

I'm guessing that message means that Python doesn't want to parse binary files.
I'm opening the file with the `"rb"` flags.

How can I parse binary files with regular expressions in Python?

**EDIT:** I'm using Python 3.2.0

Comment: I'm guessing from the reference to bytes-like object that you're using Python 3, is that correct?

Comment: Are you asking about how to run `re`'s functions against a [**binary file**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-binary-file)? Or are you asking about how to run `re`'s functions against a [**bytes-like object**](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytes-like-object)? I'm interested in the former, but these answers only seem to address the latter (in particular, they don't give any clue, as far as I can tell, as to how to run `re`'s functions against non-`rb'\x0d?\x0a'`-delimited files that may be larger than the available RAM).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you use Python 3 .

> 1.Opening a file in **binary mode** is simple but subtle. The only difference
>   from opening it in text mode is that
>   the mode parameter contains a **'b'**
>   character.
>
> ........
>
> 4.Here’s one difference, though: a **binary stream** object has no encoding
>   attribute. That makes sense, right?
>   **You’re reading (or writing) bytes**, not
>   strings, so there’s no conversion for
>   Python to do.
>
> http://www.diveintopython3.net/files.html#read

Then, in Python 3, since a binary stream from a file is a stream of bytes, a regex to analyse a stream from a file must be defined with a sequence of bytes, not a sequence of characters.

> In Python 2, a string was an array of
>   bytes whose character encoding was
>   tracked separately. If you wanted
>   Python 2 to keep track of the
>   character encoding, you had to use a
>   Unicode string (u'') instead. But in
>   Python 3, a string is always what
>   Python 2 called a Unicode string —
>   that is, an array of Unicode
>   characters (of possibly varying byte
>   lengths).
>
> http://www.diveintopython3.net/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html

and

> **In Python 3, all strings are sequences**
>   **of Unicode characters**. There is no
>   such thing as a Python string encoded
>   in UTF-8, or a Python string encoded
>   as CP-1252. “Is this string UTF-8?” is
>   an invalid question. UTF-8 is a way of
>   encoding characters as a sequence of
>   bytes. If you want to take a string
>   and turn it into a sequence of bytes
>   in a particular character encoding,
>   Python 3 can help you with that.
>
> http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html#boring-stuff

and

> 4.6. Strings vs. Bytes# Bytes are bytes; characters are an abstraction.
>   An immutable sequence of Unicode
>   characters is called a string. An
>   immutable sequence of
>   numbers-between-0-and-255 is called a
>   bytes object.
>
> ....
>
> 1.**To define a bytes object, use the b' '  “byte literal” syntax**. Each byte
>   within the byte literal can be an
>   ASCII character or an encoded
>   hexadecimal number from \x00 to \xff
>   (0–255).
>
> http://www.diveintopython3.net/strings.html#boring-stuff

So you will define your regex as follows

```
pat = re.compile(b'[a-f]+\d+')
```

and not as

```
pat = re.compile('[a-f]+\d+')
```

More explanations here:

[15.6.4. Can’t use a string pattern on a bytes-like object](http://www.diveintopython3.net/case-study-porting-chardet-to-python-3.html)

Comment: @John Machin What do you mean, please ?

Comment: Is any legal regular expression at risk of confusing a regex  for a \x00 or any valid alternatives to representing binary data? My IDE is complaining that there is an invalid escape sequence \d in my byte string.

Comment: Why is it that examples people make always use hard-coded strings? This doesn't help at all if the regex pattern is read from a text file into a plain string without also explaining how to convert it to a (*compatible*) binary-string. 

Comment: @avatarofhope2 You should instead type `br'…\d…'` *or* `b'…\\d…'`. Python doesn't have a separate Regex type like e.g. [JS does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), only strings, for which the `re` library expects for a digit "metachar" an *actual* ASCII backslash followed by an ASCII small D.

Answer (score 35):

In your `re.compile` you need to use a `bytes` object, signified by an initial `b`:

```
r = re.compile(b"(This)")
```

This is Python 3 being picky about the difference between strings and bytes.

Comment: And what if the pattern isn't hard-coded in the script but rather read from a text file into a string variable? How do you convert it to a (*compatible*) byte string? 

Comment: @Synetech use `.encode()` on the string object to make it a bytes object

Answer (score -3):

This is working for me for python 2.6

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(".*(ELF).*")
>>> f = open("/bin/ls")
>>> x = f.readline()
>>> r.match(x).groups()
('ELF',)
```

Comment: This code `import re; r = re.compile("(This)"); f = open(r"C:\WINDOWS\system32\mspaint.exe", "rb"); x = f.readline(); r.match(x).groups()`
returns the same error as my original post