# Parse a binary file with Regular Expressions?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I've got two bytes-type variable that I've concatenated (separated by a space) so I can send it as one variable to a server (socket programming). What I'm trying to figure out is how to then separate them and assign them to their original variables using regular expressions. I've consulted [regular expressions parsing a binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618988/regular-expression-parsing-a-binary-file) but it wouldn't work for me. [Here](https://prnt.sc/hjjn54) is my output after trying the expression as so just to get the cipher variable

```
ciphertext = re.match(b'\S', ciphertext)
```

It generally only matches the first couple characters and returns an object, which isn't what I'm wanting. What am I doing wrong?

edit: I'm probably doing it the hard way. Honestly, any recommendation on how to send 2 bytes objects over a socket using UDP. Its proving really difficult

Comment: Please include your output in your question, not as a link to a screenshot.

Comment: But in summary, the reason you're getting an object is because that's what `re.match` returns.  It gives you back a `match object` (or `None` if the string doesn't match) which allows you to work with the matching text.  I'm not entirely sure what you were expecting that call to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using str.rpartition to solve my problems. Wasn't the most obvious answer, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using regex to do this?. You should take a look at the [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module:

```
In [1]: import struct

In [2]: magic = b'\xcf\xfa\xed\xfe'

In [3]: decoded = struct.unpack('<I', magic)[0]

In [4]: hex(decoded)
Out[4]: '0xfeedfacf'
```

Also, you can use [this](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577610-decoding-binary-files/?in=user-4175703) recipe for decoding binary files

Comment: Can  I use structs to combine two byte objects into one variable that can later be re-separated? If i could copy the whole value from each variable and put them into a struct, that would be perfect, but it keeps clipping the values.