# How to parse a binary file in python

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, binary

I am still new to the python when it comes to parsing data. I'd like solve this problem that can be seen in the image and the respective "telemetry.bin" and 'TLM_LIST.csv" are in the google drive folder. I am able to operate the csv file using pandas but don't how to deal with the bin file as it throws output like below:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h_15khW2abjT8V6L38VSrqpb5vrmDfa-

*b'\n\x00\x00\x07\x08\x01\x0b\xe7\x08\xc3\x0b\xd9\x07\x9e\x04\xe4\x00\x00\x0c\xef\x00\x99\x1f\xdb\x00\x00\x00\x00\xbe\xef\xca\xfe\x00\x00\x01\x00\x02\x04\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00mg2878_a A\x00\xc1\x00\x8fe\xb8>\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00%~\x1a\x00\x00\x00\x96\x00\x00\x00\x91\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8fe\xb8?\x00\x00\x00\x00'*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g7Pqh.jpg)

Please I really wanna learn so please help. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your code with us?

Comment: The binary data has to have some format and without knowing that, there really isn't anything we can do to help. If this is a standard format, there is a good chance that a python module has been written to parse it.

Comment: The format is basically just like TLM_LIST.csv (the file is in the drive).

Comment: I tried following, the output I get is "None" may be due to incorrect format. It is actually a dataframe.

from beacontools import parse_packet

with open("telemetry.bin","rb") as b_f:
    data=b_f.read()
    print(data)
    
    da = parse_packet(data)

Comment: # Can this link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618988/regular-expression-parsing-a-binary-file?r=SearchResults&s=1|139.4969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression parsing a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618988/regular-expression-parsing-a-binary-file)

Comment: I am still trying your suggestion.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Obviously the data in bin file is just like that TLM_LIST.csv file with columns ['byte','commands', and so on]. So during parsing (converting data to readable format), do I need to each column to store the respective parsed data in it?