# cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, python-re

i'm creating a crawler in python to list all links in a website but i'm getting an error i can't see what cause it
the error is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vul_scanner.py", line 8, in <module>
    vuln_scanner.crawl(target_url)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo x240\Documents\website\website\spiders\scanner.py", line 18, in crawl
    href_links= self.extract_links_from(url)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo x240\Documents\website\website\spiders\scanner.py", line 15, in extract_links_from
    return re.findall('(?:href=")(.*?)"', response.content)
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo x240\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\re.py", line 241, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

my code is : in scanner.py file:

```
# To ignore numpy errors:
#     pylint: disable=E1101
import urllib
import requests
import re
from urllib.parse import urljoin

class Scanner:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.target_url = url
        self.target_links = []

    def extract_links_from(self, url):
        response = requests.get(url)
        return re.findall('(?:href=")(.*?)"', response.content)

    def crawl(self, url):
        href_links= self.extract_links_from(url)
        for link in href_links:
            link = urljoin(url, link)   

            if "#" in link:
                link = link.split("#")[0]

            if self.target_url in link and link not in self.target_links:
                self.target_links.append(link)
                print(link)
                self.crawl(link)
```

in vul_scanner.py file :

```
import scanner
# To ignore numpy errors:
#     pylint: disable=E1101


target_url = "https://www.amazon.com"
vuln_scanner = scanner.Scanner(target_url)
vuln_scanner.crawl(target_url)
```

the command i run is : **python vul_scanner.py**

Comment: sharing the full error message might help people to answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return re.findall('(?:href=")(.*?)"', response.content)
```

`response.content` in this case is of type binary. So either you use `response.text`, so you get pure text and can process it as you plan on doing now, or you  can check this out:

[Regular expression parsing a binary file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618988/regular-expression-parsing-a-binary-file)

In case you want to continue down the binary road.

Cheers